# Socket.io assigning same id to all clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to save all the connected in clients in an object. But as I figured, the connected clients all have the same id's. So if the object `connections` has all the connected sockets, when i try to send a message to `connections['mac']` it just appears on my screen as sent by me to me. Here is the auth code:

```
app.post('/auth', function(req, res){   // routes.auth(hash, db, io, pseudoArray, connections)
    var username = req.body.username,
        password = req.body.password;
    if (username != "" && password != ""){
        authenticate(username, password, db, hash, function(err, user){
            if (user) {
                // Regenerate session when signing in
                // to prevent fixation 
                console.log('user authenticated');
                req.session.regenerate(function(){
                    req.session.user = user.name;
                    req.session.success = 'Authenticated as ' + user.name
                    + ' click to <a href="/logout">logout</a>. '
                    + ' You may now access <a href="/restricted">/restricted</a>.';

                    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
                        socket.set('pseudo', req.session.user, function(){
                            pseudoArray.push(req.session.user);
                            var sessionuser = req.session.user;
                            socket.emit('pseudoStatus', 'ok');
                            connections[req.session.user] = socket;
                            console.log("user " + req.session.user + " connected");
                        });
                    });
                    res.cookie('rememberme', '1', { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
                    res.redirect('home');
                });
            } else {
                console.log('auth failed');
                req.session.error = 'Authentication failed, please check your '
                    + ' username and password.'
                    + ' (use "tj" and "foobar")';
                res.redirect('login');
            }
        }); 
    } else {
        res.redirect('connect');
    }
});
```

The code where I send the message to other client:

```
exports.addfriend = function(connections, io){
    return function(req, res){
        // var collection = db.get('go1');
        var username = req.session.user;
        var friend = req.body.name;
        console.log(connections[''+friend+'']);
        connections[''+friend+''].emit('addRequest', username);
        return;
    }
}
```

I had this auth code in the routes file earlier and I figure I should be running this off app.js. I did that and it still doesnt work as I want it. Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Where is the code where you send a message to one of the connections?

Comment: updated the question with messaging code

Comment: Can you reduce this to a single node.js file and html file that demonstrates the problem?  I think there are too many missing parts to fully answer this at the moment. It could be related the the session regeneration, but it's very hard to tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you have a Socket.IO incoming connection handler inside one of your HTTP routes. That means the handler is only applied after the route is accessed, besides the fact that you should only have a single Socket.IO connection handler.

What you need to do is separate your HTTP and Socket.IO handlers, and since you're using sessions, allow Socket.IO to handle the authorization.

First, move your socket handler outside of the HTTP handler:

```
app.post('/', handler);
io.sockets.on('connection', handler);
```

Then, define the Socket.IO authorization setting to fetch the session object from Express. Assuming you are using `express.cookieParser()` since you have sessions, and a session store, we need to externally reference them:

```
var MemoryStore = express.session.MemoryStore;

var session_key = 'express.sid';
var session_secret = 'for signed cookies';
var session_store = new MemoryStore();

var cookieParser = express.cookieParser(session_secret);

app.use(cookieParser);
app.use(express.session({
  secret: session_secret,
  store: session_store,
  key: session_key
});
```

Now that the session object and cookie parser are accessible, we can define the authorization setting:

```
io.set('authorization', function(handshake, callback) {
  if (handshake.headers.cookie) {
    cookieParser(handshake, null, function(err) {
      // Use depends on whether you have signed cookies
      // handshake.sessionID = handshake.cookies[session_key];
      handshake.sessionID = handshake.signedCookies[session_key];

      session_store.get(handshake.sessionID, function(err, session) {
        if (err || !session) {
          callback('Error or no session.', false);
        } else {
          handshake.session = session;
          callback(null, true);
        }
      });
    });
  } else {
    callback('No session cookie found.', false);
  }
});
```

What this code does is it checks if the client has a session cookie. If not, it does not authorize the Socket.IO connection. If it does, it parses the cookie, finds the associated session, and stores the session with the socket. Now you can access session properties by socket:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  req.session.user = 'genericusername';
  res.send(200);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var session = socket.handshake.session;
  session.user // genericusername
});
```

As for your code, it would then look like the following:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var MemoryStore = express.session.MemoryStore;

var session_key = 'express.sid';
var session_secret = 'for signed cookies';
var session_store = new MemoryStore();

var cookieParser = express.cookieParser(session_secret);

app.use(cookieParser);
app.use(express.session({
  secret: session_secret,
  store: session_store,
  key: session_key
});
```

The route handler:

```
app.post('/auth', function(req, res) {
  var username = req.body.username,
  var password = req.body.password;

  if (username != '' && password != '') {
    authenticate(username, password, db, hash, function(err, user) {
      if (user) {
        req.session.regenerate(function() {
          req.session.user = user.name;
          req.session.success = 'Authenticated as ' + user.name + ' click to <a href="/logout">logout</a>. You may now access <a href="/restricted">/restricted</a>.';
          res.cookie('rememberme', '1', {
            maxAge: 900000,
            httpOnly: true
          });
          res.redirect('/home');
        });
      } else {
        req.session.error = 'Authentication failed, please check your username and password. (use "tj" and "foobar")';
        res.redirect('/login');
      }
    }); 
  } else {
    res.redirect('/connect');
  }
});
```

And then the Socket.IO configuration:

```
io.set('authorization', function(handshake, callback) {
  if (handshake.headers.cookie) {
    cookieParser(handshake, null, function(err) {
      // Use depends on whether you have signed cookies
      // handshake.sessionID = handshake.cookies[session_key];
      handshake.sessionID = handshake.signedCookies[session_key];

      session_store.get(handshake.sessionID, function(err, session) {
        if (err || !session) {
          callback('Error or no session.', false);
        } else {
          handshake.session = session;
          callback(null, true);
        }
      });
    });
  } else {
    callback('No session cookie found.', false);
  }
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var session = socket.handshake.sessionl
  socket.set('pseudo', session.user, function() {
    socket.emit('pseudoStatus', 'ok');
    connections[session.user] = socket;
  });
});
```

Comment: brilliant. thanks. i'd be trying this out right now. one thing that i want to know is: i don't want the socket to be active on all pages. JUST the actual chat page. how to do that?

Comment: You can check `handshake.url` during the authorization is taking place. A simple `if (handshake.url != '/page') callback('Page not authorized.', false);`.

Comment: okay. i gotta do that. I have implemented the changes you suggested above, and I am getting "debug - authorized / warn  - handshake error Error or no session." at the console. any ideas?

Comment: You have `handshake.signedCookies['_secret_cookie_'];` even though you set the key to `express.sid`. Therefore, use `handshake.signedCookies['express.sid'];`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39211/discussion-between-amit-and-hexacyanide)

Answer (score 1):

You have an `io.sockets.on('connection'...` inside of a single users login.  So each time a user logs in, there will be another listener added.

So it may look like this ( someone logs in, then they connect to socket )

User1 logs in
User 1 connects to socket ( pseudo as himself )

User 2 logs in
User 2 connects to socket ( pseudo as User 1, then pseudo as User 2)

User 3 logs in
User 3 connects to socket ( pseudo as 1 , 2, then 3

If user 1 refreshes the page, he will be pseudo as 1, 2, 3, as well

The problem is listening more and more each time someone logs in.

You need to listen to connect outside of a function that happens multiple times.

I usually do something like the following

in english:  The user loads up a page, he connects to socket io, then he does a ajax $.get so the server can use his session to give him a token that will authorize his socket.  He then sends the token and the server knows that socket is authorized.

```
app.get('/socket_token', function(req, res, next){
  var socket_token = Math.random();/* probably want to use crypto here instead*/
  mysql.query('update users set users.socket_token = ? where users.id = ?', [  socket_token, req.session.userId], function(err, result){
    if(result)
      res.json({userId: req.session.userId, socket_token: socket_token});
    else
      res.send('DOH!');
   });
});

global.all_my_sockets = []

io.sockets.on('connnection', function(socket){

  socket.emit('hey_you_are_connected');

  socket.on('authorize', function(credentials, callback){
    if(credentials.userId)
      mysql.query('select * from users where id = ?', [credentials.userId], function(err, user){
        if(user.socket_token == credentials.socket_token){
          socket.set('authorized', true);
          socket.set('userId', user.id);

          // This is probably bad since what if he has 2 browser windows open?
          all_my_sockets[user.id] = socket

          callback('that socket token is authorized');
        } else {
         //handle it
         callback('that socket token is no good');
        }
      })

  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    socket.get('userId', function(id){
      if(id)
        delete all_my_sockets[id];
    });
  });
})
```

and on the client side

```
socket = io.connect();
socket.on('hey_you_are_connected', function(){
  $.get('/socket_token', function(credentials){
    socket.emit('authorize_token', credentials, function(res){
      console.log(res);  // did we authorize socket?
    });
  });
});
```

I typed this off the top of my head so there might be an error, but it should be pretty close to what you're trying to do.

So there are some problems with saving sockets in all_my_sockets[id], namely that you can only have 1 socket per user and what if they have multiple browsers open?

You should try structuring your code differently so you don't need a global bunch of sockets, otherwise, just push them to the array so multiple can exist for each user.

```
all_my_sockets.push(socket);
...
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  if( all_my_sockets.indexOf(socket) != -1 )
    all_my_sockets.splice( all_my_sockets.indexOf(socket), 1 )
})
```

if you pushed every socket to the array, before they were authorized, then to actually find the socket then, you would have to go through each:

```
_.each(all_my_sockets, function(socket){
  socket.get('userId', function(userId) { 
    if(userId)
      doSomething(socket)
    else
      doSomethingUnAuthorized(socket)
   });
 });
```

obviously this is very slow, which is the same reason why there aren't a whole lot of people saving sockets to a global place like this.  Try doing what you're trying to do with more callbacks and rethink the problem from scratch.   Or leave it as a hack until you get more traffic and it becomes a problem of performance. :)